# Mysterious HttpSession and session-config dependency

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, ssl

Good day. I'm developing a Java web app with Servlets\JSP using Tomcat 7.0. During request from client I put and object into the session and use forward. After the forward processing the same request the object can be retreived if the secure parameter is false otherwise it is not stored in session.

```
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
```

I've figured out that "...cookies can be created with the 'secure' flag, which ensures that the browser will never transmit the specified cookie over non-SSL...". I've configured Tomcat to use SSL, but that haven't helped. Changing the tracking mode to SSL haven't helped as well. How do session-config and HttpSession object correlate in this case? What could be the problem?

Comment: Configuring Tomcat to use SSL is one thing. Are you also *actually* invoking HTTPS requests instead of HTTP requests? E.g. `https://localhost:8080/foo`.

Comment: Hi, BalusC. No, I do not. I just want to know why the object put in session disappears after forward during the same request.

Comment: But if you're not using HTTPS, then the session can't be maintained because you told the session cookie to be secure only (i.e. it's available on HTTPS only).